# Single Depot Capacitated single Vehicle with different delivery magnitudes

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, logic

I want to build an algorithm that gives the optimum route (minimum overall distance and it may have cycles) through which a single delivery vehicle, which has a limited capacity and starts from a fixed point (depot) and also ends at that point, can deliver the required amount of products on nodes.

Where should I start and what techniques/logic should I use? I have knowledge of graphs, trees, Dijkstra's algorithm etc.

I also think that this will be related to the Travelling Salesman problem in someway.

I will implement this on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

First implement Dijkstra's algorithm and find the shortest distance list. Then start from a node and deliver to the node that has the shortest distance from the selected node.
you should keep checking the capacity of the vehicle, if it reaches its limit so go back to the starting vertex, refill, and continue from the node where you left from.
Repeat this process until all the nodes have been reached.